# Connect an Android to an Ad Hoc network?

Tags: ad-hoc-networks

I'm working with a homemade security system made of Raspberry Pis that are connected via an Ad Hoc network. I want to see if I could connect my Android to that network and really haven't found any recent examples. A lot of previous posts were saying that Android doesn't support ad hoc networks and I don't know if that's still true.

Comment: Does the wireless card of the device that is hosting Ad Hoc network supports Access Point (AP) interface? If you are running Linux on it, run this command to know it: `iw list` and look into the output the heading `Supported interface modes`.